# How to prevent object's being promoted to gen2

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection

Runtime marks gen2 memory regions (aka card tables) via write barriers to detect if a younger generation object reference is written to gen2 object.if a gen 0 or 1 collection occurs.they are checked afterwards. While marking part affects assignment performance, obviously GC spends more time to collect Gen0 or 1.

I have pooled objects which are written references of short lived objects very frequently.

What i want to achieve is have those pooled objects always stay in gen0 but i cant think of any tehnique. Also i want to discuss if it is benefital. Maybe GC team should include it as a feature?

In short, i have long-lived objects. they hold references to both persistent and volatile objects...  volitile object references are written to it very frequently which make them scanned every gen0 + write barrier - card table management overhead. what do you think the best way to squeze best performance?

edit: it is about zero allocation asnctaskmethodbuilder. uploded working sample to github:
https://github.com/crowo/LightTask/tree/master/LightTask

Comment: Your statement is a bit of an oxymoron. You want to have pooled objects with short-lived object references? The entire purpose of pooling is to allocate long-lived objects that are then recycled to avoid additional allocations. How could you have a short-lived pooled object? And if the pooled objects are held for the duration of the application, why does it matter to you if they are promoted to gen2?

Comment: The point of Gen0 is that it only contains newly created, completely unused objects; objects which are nearly free to collect. Putting long-live pooled things in there would kill the optimization. You want your long-lived, pooled buffers to settle into their Gen2 home, where they are never going to be moved or collected. Why do you think your idea is a good one?

Comment: @DavidL long lived objects are always needed thus pooled. but they temporarly hold reference short lived objects. they are cleared before returning to pool. they hold references to long lived objects also..

Comment: @Flydog57 my pooled objects are not buffers. they are used during whole application lifetime but hold references to gen0 objects. moving them gen2 and checking them every gen0 already defeats your assumptions.  making them always stay in gen0  seemms to defeat my puepose too. it seems it isnt much different than re-allocating and collecting them everytime but it prevents consuming GC budget which is a win. probably its best pooling persistent parts, and making volatile part another class and let them get collected everytime.

Comment: You should consider splitting your object structures out or clean up resources when you are done with them. Moving long-term resources to gen 0 simply doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @DavidL it makes sense. see my other comment.

Comment: @ömerhayyam perhaps you should add code that demonstrates what is currently happening.

Comment: @DavidL its not that hard to understand the sitıation. i have long-lived objects. they hold references to both persistent and volatile objects...  volitile object references are written to it very frequently which make them scanned every gen0 + write barrier - card table management overhead.

Comment: I'm not following your reasoning. Have (say) a long-lived (Gen2) cache of references to short lived (Gen0) objects doesn't cost any more than having the cache in Gen0. Memory is memory. Gen2 Memory access (or cross-generation Memory access)doesn't cost more than Gen0 to Gen0 access

Comment: @Flydog57 first, if you misunderstood it isnt a cache for short lived objects. they are objects usefull in application throughout. problem is write-barrier cost plus gen0 gc now have to check-scan gen2 memory which is more work. accessing objects is already always same.

Comment: @ömerhayyam again, perhaps if you _shared code relevant to your issue_, there would be more understanding and less speculation.

Comment: Have you seen evidence of this in testing?  When I worked in MSFT support, most GC/perf issues were related to the "Too Many Almost-Long-Life Objects" issue Rico Mariani describes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973837 or, very often, LOH issues.  In both cases, the result were too frequent Gen2 collections-slowing things down.  What you are talking about would seem to add cost to Gen0 collections, which doesn't seem to be a good strategy.  But, I'm open to read an edited question that describes your situation in more detail

Comment: Can’t you redesign the logic? Instead of modifying the long lived object, to reference the short lived objects, create a new dedicated short-lived object containing the references to all needed short lived objects and the long lived object. As long as you can have an object containing all information (which this redesign would still support), you should be able to express the application logic atop this object.

Comment: @Holger good suggestion, but old objects also needs to use young objects.

Comment: Well, it would imply that the affected methods are changed to receive the needed young objects as parameters rather than reading them from old object’s fields. The new class whose instances reference both, old and young objects, could introduce convenience methods which delegate to those methods and hide the parameter passing. But since that may involve a lot of changes, I made my comment a question, whether such redesign is possible. If the old object is of some library’s type that you can’t change, that’s obviously not an option…

Comment: @Holger again great suggestion. but my situation is a bit different. i have to return that young objects when asked and/or they must survive between async operations. see my edits. ive added github repository.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are describing indeed exists. Card tables scanning and promotions that results from it indeed may add *some* overhead. I've explained this mechanism in [my video here](https://youtu.be/K3uaXipc1xQ?list=PLpUkQYy-K8Y-wYcDgDXKhfs6OT8fFQtVm&t=5278). Unfortunatelly, it is just a feature and/or caveat of most generational GCs. Moreover, it may lead to [*nepotism*](https://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/n.html).

**BUT**, the main question is whether it is a real problem or you just don't feel comfortable with the knowledge that such overhead happens? In other words, you should follow **"measure first"** approach.

Unfortunatelly there are no super easy metrics to measure the overhead from this particular problem. But typically we are doing following things:

- since .NET 5 we have ["generational aware analysis"](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/40332) available in the runtime itself, which we can see in PerfView's Generational Aware view. It will allow you to see which gen1/gen2 objects are holding references to younger generations. This may be not super useful in your case, as it sounds you already know where it happens
- record .NET trace and look for `MarkWithType` event. If there are many `Type="3"` events (they represent `GC_ROOT_OLDER` reason of promotion) with big amount of `Promoted` bytes, it may suggest indeed you may have a problem:

  ```
  Event Name   Time MSec   Process Name   Rest  
  MarkWithType 186.370 Process(28820) HeapNum="5" Type="3" Promoted="62,104,694"
  MarkWithType 186.421 Process(28820) HeapNum="0" Type="3" Promoted="52,687,589"
  MarkWithType 186.633 Process(28820) HeapNum="3" Type="3" Promoted="49,932,696"
  ```

  **But only** if you also correlate such GCs with long pause times or *% TIme in GC*.

So, only if you measure it somehow is a problem, and this typically will be when having volume of dozens of GBs, try to solve it. As it is an inherent consequence of how .NET GC is built, there is no easy workaround though. Here are some typical ideas:

- try to follow @david-l advice to split object structures. Maybe old objects may reference those young, temporary objects only by some index, not a reference
- or just try to redesign it all as @holger suggests to avoid those references at all
- or make young, temporary objects also pooled using `ObjectPool` so they eventually all be living in gen2
- or may those temporary objects structs that are inlined in long-living pooled objects

Comment: added git repository. see question.